# SQL Server stored procedure waiting parameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
exec GetBob @id=3
```

But when I call this stored procedure in a function, I get the error:

> The procedure or function expects the @id parameter

But `@id` is the correct parameter (get value).

```
public List<Bob> GetBob(int id)
{
    try
    {
        connection();
        con.Open();

        DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@id", id);

        IList<Bob> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<Bob>(con, "GetBob", param).ToList();
        con.Close();

        return EmpList.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you don't need `DynamicParameters` here; just `new { id }` as the parameter is fine. Additional side note: `.AsList()` is marginally more efficient than `.ToList()`; Additional additional side note: did you know you don't actually need to `Open()` a connection for dapper, especially for scenarios like this? Dapper will deal with it.

Comment: Additional additional additional side note: don't `catch` just to `throw` - don't even `try` - just let it happen if that's what you're going to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. You should be good. You need to provide `command Type` that it is `Stored Procedure`.

```
public List<Bob> GetBob(int id)
{
    try
    {
        connection();
        con.Open();
        DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@id", id);
        IList<Bob> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<Bob>(
                          con, "GetBob",param,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        con.Close();
        return EmpList.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Express parametr "@id" parameter that is not specified." (My translate)